# Cannot get the latest DB data by "select" sql command, after updated that data by "update" command by another mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql, connection

there are two mysql connection in my python script. example:

```
conn1 = mdb.connect(server, user, pw, db)
conn2 = mdb.connect(server, user, pw, db)

#1. then, I execute "select" sql command to select table A by conn1, 
#2. after that, I execute "update" sql command to update table A by conn2,
#3. finally, I execute "select" sql command again to select table A by conn1,
```

but finally, the result of #3 is same as #1; however, after #2, i saw the data is updated in mysql workbench.

Is anybody know why #3 cannot get the latest data?

## following is my python codes:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import time

conn1 = mdb.connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DB)
cur1 = conn.cursor()
count1 = cur.execute("SELECT trigger_time FROM trigger_set WHERE id=1")
data1 = cur.fetchall()
cur1.close()
print data1

conn2 = mdb.connect(SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DB)
cur2 = conn2.cursor()
cur2.execute("update trigger_set set trigger_time = '2013/8/30 17:15' where id=1")
conn2.commit()
cur2.close()

cur1 = conn.cursor()
count1 = cur.execute("SELECT trigger_time FROM trigger_set WHERE id=1")
data1 = cur.fetchall()
print data1
```

Comment: when you have close the cur1 once. arent we supposed to open it back?you arent opening it back and still using it so may be its fetching the old result. hence, #1 and #3 are the same despite #2 query working

Answer (score 0):

Things would work if you commit your conn1 before selecting again.. or just enable auto_commit to True.

```
conn1.commit()
```

This has been talked about here: http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/discussion/70461/thread/efea588e

BTW your code contains conn and cur variables which have not been defined..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with reusing the same cursor `cur1' for step 1 and 3.Try using a different cursor or connection for your last select too.